# Detect if a series of numbers is sequential in bash/awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk, range, sequence

So I have a series of scripts that generate intermediary text files along the way as a means of storing information across different scripts. Essentially the scripts detect rows within data that have been approved by the user for removal. The line numbers that are to be removed from the source file are stored in a file.

For example, say I have a source data file like this:

```
    a1,b1,c1,d1
    a2,b2,c2,d2
    a3,b3,c3,d3
    a4,b4,c4,d4
    a5,b5,c5,d5
    a6,b6,c6,d6
    a7,b7,c7,d7
```

And the intermediary file would contain something like this:

```
    1 3 4 5 6
```

Which would result, when the script is run, in an output data file as follows:

```
    a2,b2,c2,d2
    a7,b7,c7,d7
```

This all works fine, there is nothing to fix in this code. The problem is, when I'm dealing with actual data files sometimes there are literally thousands of numbers stored in the intermediary file for removal. This means I can't use a loop, because it will take a massive amount of time, and my current method of using `sed` gets overloaded with a `error: too many arguments`. Many of the line numbers are consecutive, so here's where I get to my question:

Is there a way in bash or awk to detect whether a series of space-separated numbers are consecutive?

I can sort out everything beyond that, I'm just stumped on how I could do this in one/a series of step(s). My plan, if I can detect consecutive values, is to change the intermediary file from:

```
    1 3 4 5 6
```

To:

```
    1 3-6
```

And then I'll be able to write code that will run on each range of values in a more manageable way.

If possible I'd like to avoid looping through each value and checking individually whether or not it's one step above the previous value, since I'm dealing with tens of thousands of numbers in a list.

If this is not possible in bash/awk, is there another way to accomplish this task to reduce the overall number of arguments passed to my script and greatly reduce the chances of encountering an error for too many arguments?

Comment: are you sure it is `sed` that is issuing `too many arguments`? Are you passing a big list of files to `sed` for it to process? Then that error msg is more likely from your shell. Do you know about `xargs`? It may be able to help. Without seeing a sample context of your `sed` and `too many files` error we can't really tell where the problem is. Also step back if you can, 10 of thousands of numbers, sounds like something that should be in a database. Maybe not something you can do tonight, but how much more might this program grow: Start planning the migration now? Good luck.

Comment: It won't take long to process even millions of numbers squishing consecutive numbers into ranges.  The Perl to do that is not hard.  Is your intermediary file one line of input or is each number on its own line or some hybrid mixture?  It only affects the input processing; the rest of the algorithm is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cat`, `join`, and `cut`:

Files *infile* and *ids*:

```
a1,b1,c1,d1         1
a2,b2,c2,d2         3
a3,b3,c3,d3         4
a4,b4,c4,d4         5
a5,b5,c5,d5         6
a6,b6,c6,d6
a7,b7,c7,d7
```

Removal of selected lines:

```
$ join -v 2 ids <(cat -n infile) | cut -f 2 -d ' '
a2,b2,c2,d2
a7,b7,c7,d7
```

**What's going on:**

- First, the initial file receives an id on each line, with `cat -n infile`;
- then, the resulting file is joined on the first column with the file holding the ids;
- only non-matching lines from second file are printed -- `join -v 2`;
- the first column, with the ids, is removed;
- and, it's a neat shell *one-liner* (:

In case your file with ids is written as an unique line, you can still make use of the above one-liner, simply adding a translation on the file with ids, as follows:

```
$ join -v 2 <(tr ' ' '\n' ids) <(cat -n infile) | cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

Comment: @Simon astutely solved the question I asked which would allow me to carry out the somewhat complex solution I had come up with, but this solves my entire problem in one fell swoop. If there was a way I'd give the correct answer to both of you. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
BEGIN {
    getline < "intermediate.txt"
    split($0, skippedlines, " ")
    skipindex = 1
}
{
    if (skippedlines[skipindex] == NR)
        ++skipindex;
    else
        print
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@jmihalicza's answer nicely uses awk to solve the whole problem of selecting the lines from source file that match those in the intermediate file. For completeness, the following awk program reduces the list of individual line numbers to ranges, where possible, which I think answers the original question:

```
    { for (j = 1; j <= NF; j++) {
        lin[i++] = $j;
        }
    }

END {
    start = lin[0];
    j = 1;
    while (j <= i) {
        end = start
        while (lin[j] == (lin[j-1]+1)) {
            end = lin[j++];
            }
        if ((end+0) > (start+0)) {
                printf "%d-%d ",start,end
            } else {
                printf "%d ",start
            }
        start = lin[j++];
        }
    }
```

Given this script, which I've called `merge.awk` and a file `testlin.txt` as follows:

```
1 3 4 5 6 9 10 11 13 15
```

... we can do this:

```
$ awk -f merge.awk <testlin.txt
1 3-6 9-11 13 15
```

Comment: Perhaps simpler: `awk 'NR==1{ l=$0; printf $0; next }
$0!=l+1{if (r)printf( "-%d",l); printf " "$0;r=0}
$0==l+1{r=1}
{l=$0}
END{ if(r) printf( "-%d", l); print ""}
' RS=' '`

Comment: Simon this answer is an excellent solution that solves the problem I'd set out to figure out, but the solution @Rubens posed allows me to cleanly solve my larger problem. I'd really like to give the correct answer to you both, but I can't. Sorry, hope an upvote will suffice!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\S+/&d/g;s/\s+/\n/g' intermediate_file | sed -f - source_file
```

Change the intermediate file into a sed script.